# Servidor apache não executa arquivos .php

Tags: php, linux, apache

Acabei de instalar o Apache e PHP no meu linux, e Todos meus arquivos .php estão aparecendo este seguinte erro de log:

> [Sat Mar 07 12:10:48 2015] [error] [client ::1] PHP Warning:  Unknown:
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0 [Sat Mar
>   07 12:10:48 2015] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown:
>   Failed opening required '/var/www/index.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0

Dentro deste arquivo tem somente isso:

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

A distro que uso é o debian, instalei o apache, php e mysql com o seguinte comando:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente esses arquivos não tenham as permissões necessárias.

No terminal digite:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 ~/var/www/
```

Isso vai permitir a leitura e execução dos arquivos da pasta `/var/www/`.

Comment: Na verdade tinha feito apenas o sudo chmod -R 777, com o 755 deu certo, nossa obrigada mesmo :3

Comment: @any_wolf Disponha. :)